# Where is the Touch Sensor in 2.7x?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

In the Logic editor in Blender 2.7x I can't find the *Touch* sensor. Where is it? Or how duplicate it's function to detect anything.

Answer (score 3):

The *Touch* sensor has been removed, but in its place there is a updated *Collision* sensor.
[image: Collision sensor]
The *M/P* button will toggle the Collision sensor only targeting a property or material.
To target anything, just leave the property field blank.